# Real time object tracking for an indoor positioning system using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, posix, real-time, ipc

---

### **Short version**: is it a good idea to use multiple processes and memory sharing (POSIX) to divide the development in a functional way?

**Long version**: For my college project, we proposed basically a GPS for indoors (in this case a warehouse and the forklifts as users). The idea is to handle the Real-time streams from 3 ip cameras (RTSP) attached to the roof directed to the floor, process them and push the position of each forklift into a DB and a simple webpage to see the magic.

Right now we are looking the best way to tackle this problem and use a functional approach to divide the tasks (e.g. one guy writes the background remover, other guy the features extractor, other guy the position and velocity vector estimator, motion blur filter, kalman, etc) and at the end get to work together these highly specialized blocks.

We plan to use OpenCV since the performance is much better than Matlab's toolkits and it offers CUDA, TBB in case we need a boost.
Our main concern is the real-time compromise and to divide the development in a smart way, so I proposed a main process that handles the stream and via shared memory to feed the different blocks (since many of the core operations are independent of each other) this can be with POSIX or System V functions.
The best thing of this approach is that each person can develop his part independently, test perfomance and at the end add the extension to the main process.
So far the experiments with the streaming and allocate OpenCV objects in shared memory have been successful.

Does this makes sense to you guys?
Do you know a smarter way to divide and conquer?
am I reinventing the wheel?

Thank you very much for your time. Michael

Comment: Not sure, if I'd use processes - threads should suffice. But in my opinion this is a far too complex question to be properly answered here. Also depends on the OS, the machine, and the type of RT-Requirements you have.

Comment: I also think that threads should be enough: Never use a more complex feature (process and memory sharing) if you don't REALLY have to. Simple solutions are your friends...

Comment: Thank you for the replica to both of you. Our rig will be powered by Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA 6.5 and OpenCV 2.4.9. It's a pretty humble setup and that's why we have the concern with the real-time. I will follow your advice and start with simple high level functions.